# change img source based on angularjs expression

Tags: html, css, angularjs, image

So I'm trying to change the source of the image depending on an expression to see if its true or not.

**HTML**

```
<img ng-src="category.content.Value >= category.content.ValueOneWeekAgo ? 
'Images/green_arrow.png' : 'Images/red_arrow.png'" />
```

This is how the rendered html looks like:

```
<img ng-src="category.content.Value >= category.content.ValueOneWeekAgo ? 'Images/green_arrow.png' : 'Images/red_arrow.png'" 
src="category.content.Value &gt;= category.content.ValueOneWeekAgo ? 'Images/green_arrow.png' : 'Images/red_arrow.png'">
```

I know the variables contains values which was confirmed by debugging. Probably something simple but i can't seem to figure it out.

Comment: what more do you want me to explain?

Comment: do you want to change the ng-src  value from controller?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just switch the order in you expresssion to use `<` instead of `>=`.
You cannot use `>=` because browser treats it as end of html tag.

```
<img ng-src="category.content.ValueOneWeekAgo < category.content.Value  ? 'Images/green_arrow.png' : 'Images/red_arrow.png'" >
```

Other option is to put this code inside a controller and publish as new variable on `$scope`.

Comment: The result is identical to the rendered html I wrote above, part from the order of <=

Comment: thats what i ended up doing. ng-src="{{getArrowSrc(category.content.Value, category.content.ValueOneWeekAgo) }}"

Comment: You don't need `{{}}` to call a function. I think you can have other markup errors in you template that are causing error in `ng-src` attribute.